# v4l2 on RPi not working in avconv stream

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, v4l2

I have been trying to run a webcam/audio stream from usb devices on my rpi.

I have run the following commands:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 –s 640×360 r 10 –b 350k –f flv    rtmp://x.xxxxxxxx.fme.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/xxxxxxxx/streamkey
```

and

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mpeg2video -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -me_method epzs -b 2600k -bt 256k -f flv rtmp://x.xxxxxxxx.fme.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/xxxxxxxx/streamkey
```

"this command as per [this source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18202&p=216264)"

both return error:
`[video4linux2 @ 0xa3e720] Cannot find a proper format for codec_id 0, pix_fmt -1.
/dev/video0: Input/output error`

This only occurs on rpi, as my ubuntu laptop can run `avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0` perfectly using default values.

is v4l2 broken? or am I doing something wrong here.

p.s. the audio hasn't been a problem at all, so I didn't include much info on it.

Comment: What camera and OS are you using on the Pi? If you are trying to use something other than a camera you may need a different input device (i.e. not `/dev/video0`)

Comment: It's a generic Microsoft USB webcam. That crossed my mind, but I hadn't checked yet.

Comment: Try with somehting like [`fswebcam`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/) first to see if it works. You can find a list of supported devices [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams) if needed.